# Escaped sequence for apt regex

Tags: regex, apt-get, apt, posix-ere

Is there any way to natively escape a sequence in `apt`'s regex?

I have a search, for example `libpng++`, where I want to literally match the `++` part of the string. I know that I can manually escape the `++` with `\+\+`, but I need to escape the string (since it comes to me as a variable) instead of simply the manually escape the individual characters.

I've tried `apt-cache search libpng++`, `"libpng++"`, `'libpng++'`, `\"libpng++\"`, `\'libpng++\'`, `\Qlibpng++\E`, etc.

Is there any want to get this to work?

Comment: thanks for bringing that up @WiktorStribiżew. I know that I can do that, but the sequences come in as variables to me, I'd really prefer not to have to manually edit each one. I've edited the original question.

Comment: There is not really a way to escape it. But you could do something like `apt-cache search $(echo libpng++ | sed 's|+|\\+|g')`

Comment: in this case, use sed to escape each special characters.

Comment: for one or two characters, you can also use a parameter expansion: `apt-cache search ${var//+/\\+}`

Answer (score 0):

You can "treat" the variable before passing it to `apt-cache`, as in:

```
var="libpng++"
var=$(echo $var | sed 's|\([+*?]\)\\\1|g')
apt-cache search $var
```

Add any other special regex chars between `[` and `]` above.

Answer (score -1):

extra + should work. that is - `libpng+++`